# How to duplicate a list to another list (deep copy) without using clone()?

Tags: java, list, deep-copy

I want to duplicate the data from *currentList* to *newList*.
Is it possible to duplicate it without adding the clone() method inside the Object class?

I have tried a couple of codes that i found:

1.

```
List<InvoiceDetail> newList= new ArrayList<>();
newList.addAll(currentList);
```

2. 

```
newList = currentList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But as I was processing the data in the *newList*, some of the data in *currenList* will change too. If possible, I want to retain the data in *currentList*.

Comment: Calling `clone()` is the way to clone an object.

Comment: Well, you are probably better off making `InvoiceDetail` *immutable*.

Comment: @Olivier, you can't use clone() to create a deep copy and apparently that's what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want a new list to be fulfilled with the copies of `InvoiceDetail` objects, right? So, in my understanding, the problem is not how you operate with lists, but rather how `InvoiceDetail` is implemented.
I would probably go with the [copy constructor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-constructor) in the `InvoiceDetail` class. Like that:

```
class InvoiceDetail {
    
    // your existing constructors

    public InvoiceDetail(InvoiceDetail source) {
        // the logic of copying the invoice data
        // like this.someField = source.someField; etc.
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Then you could do something like that:

```
newList = currentList.stream().map(InvoiceDetail::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can that be a solution to your problem?

Alternative solution: if you do not want to bother with changing `InvoiceDetail` class, you may (if possible) create a clone object on the fly like that:

```
newList = currentList.stream().map(
    source -> {
        final InvoiceDetail target = new InvoiceDetail();
        // copy the data like target.setSomeField(source.getSomeField());
        return target;
    }
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: IMO Its better to use the first approach since creating new instances for each field helps to maintain Immutability.

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya I agree, not only that, but also it can be technically impossible, if `InvoiceDetail` doesn't expose the internal data via getters. Actually those getters are violating the encapsulation. But I do not know the context, maybe the `InvoiceDetail` class' code is not even available for editing :) That's why I suggested the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you need to retain *currenList* as is as you process data in newList. Then in that case, I think you might need have your *currenList* as  `Unmodifiable Lists`.

You can use any `List.of` implementation for creating `Unmodifiable Lists`. After that, you can simply copy element to new list & verify if they are deep equal:

```
List<InvoiceDetail> currnList = *Unmodifiable Lists* ;
List<InvoiceDetail> newList= new ArrayList<>();
newList.addAll(currentList);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(currnList.toArray(),newList.toArray())); //  returns true if they are deep equal.
```

Comment: But that is exactly opposite to what the author wants: he wants to modify objects in the new list, having corresponding objects in the old list untouched. With your implementation, as far as I'm concerned, modifying objects in the new list, he will mess up objects in the original list. "Unmodifiable list" makes list unmodifiable, not the objects inside the list.

Comment: ok, thanks for your comment, I might misunderstood problem statement, but while reading they mentioned `If possible, I want to retain the data in currentList.` so I thought there is requirement to use list which will not modify data.